-100V Power Supply from +180V Source?
I have a very high impedance load I want to run from a part of my circuit that has +180V available.
Can someone please look at this circuit sketch and tell me if this is okay or suggest a better way to do it?
My goal is to be simple as possible, but it needs to be pretty stable. The 180V source is already regulated, so I don't think there should be any major fluctuations in the source, but I don't want my design to introduce anything if possible; <200mV is ideal.
The circuit already has the +180V referenced to ground, as will be the -100V (not floating).
This is a sketch of what I think might work here, but I don't really know if there is anything to look out for or if I'm just messing up entirely.
TIA
The current draw is in the nanoamp to microamp range, so very low. I also have a 160V supply I could use, but it's more inconvenient to access and it's less stable than the 180V supply.
Impedance is over 100MOhms.


How do you expect that  circuit you've drawn to work? I'm pretty sure it won't.

Very high impedance load? Please quantify. Is the -100 V output fixed, or adjustable? What is the tolerance? Do you have a lower voltage available to power ICs (5-12V)?

To phrase @Mattman944's question another way: -100V at what current?

Without an inductor, transformer or flying capacitor, you can’t reach any voltage higher or lower than your input supply, in your case 0-180 V. Anything lower than zero or higher than 180 V can’t be generated.

No, your circuit won't work. Are you trying to make a charge pump?
If your load is very high impedance, a charge pump might be a good approach.
This is just a starting point. Unless your tolerance is very loose, you will need some type of regulation. A zener regulator might work.
Note that this circuit takes a long time to startup, that may or may not be an issue for you.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Edit: I added a simple zener regulator and reduced the capacitance so it starts up faster.
R1 will dissipate a lot of power, it should be a 2 W.
R2 will reduce the stress on C1. It may not be necessary, you will need to check the peak current rating on the capacitor.
You need to put several zeners in series to get 100 V. Here I have 47 V and 51 V. You could possibly fine-tune it by adding regular diodes in series.
Zener voltages will change somewhat over temperature, but it seems like you are in a laboratory environment and the temperature should be fairly constant.
The current draw on the 180 V supply is about 6 mA. If this is too high, you will need to make adjustments. A push-pull driver would waste less power but is more complicated.
Most of the values are just guesses without calculations to back them up.



Thanks so much for the suggestion. Yes, it needs to be quite stable, so I will have to add regulation. One thing I don't understand is where the 1kHz Square wave is coming from. Is that a result of the NMOS and the rest of your circuit, or are you assuming that I have or will build a square wave source with a 555 or something like that? TIA

Yes, you need to generate the square wave. A 555 timer will work.

For the regulator, a few high-voltage zeners in series (after a resistor). Or a better circuit would add a pass transistor. Can you give us some better specifications? How much will the load vary? How accurate does the -100 V need to be? How much ripple is allowed?

The load won't vary much at all. It's an electrostatic grid of a tube, so it's extremely high impedance and low load. The 180V supply is tightly regulated, but the tighter I can make the voltage on the grid, the better my results will be.

There is no way that circuit will deliver -100V.
The MEJ340 is just permanently turned on by the 10K resistor to its base, the unspecified capacitor does nothing.
The 100K variable resistor is just floating, only on end is connected.
You would need some sort of inverted boost converter. There is an article here to get you started, but you would have to design it yourself as 100V is an unusual requirement in most circumstances.
