QSpice sim results
I created this power supply that take 180VDC and outputs about -100VDC. Someone else here suggested this topology in another thread to me. -100V Power Supply from +180V Source?
I was able to run it in Circuitlab online, but when I try to model it in LTSpice or QSpice, it gives bad results.
In CircuitLab the voltage takes about 200ms or so to level off on the output, which is between D3 and R3, so I did 300ms transient sim with maximum steps to make it faster.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Update: I realized that I didn't place a resistor on the schematic between C2 and D3 on the top side. After doing that, I got an error from QSpice: "Warning: Singular matrix. Check node S•M1"
I ended up having to replace the Infineon NMOS with one of the models in the QSpice library and I chose one with similar attributes, UF3C120150.
After that, I realized I had a couple things messed up in the 555 circuit, so I modelled that separately and now I'm getting a pulsed 1k output, but I'm not seeing the DC offset that I am supposed to get.
Without the 2.5V offset on the gate of the transistor, it looks like QSpice is showing about -22V.
I think somehow it's down to the DC offset on the 555 timer output, but not sure how to fix that. This is what I had in CircuitLab to the best of my memory.


Another Update:
I changed the power supply to the 555 timer to 7.5V. I am using a 12V source anyway, so I swapped things around and now I'm getting about -96V, which is pretty close to correct. I wish I could get it a little lower, maybe even have it be adjustable, but the two zeners are what's controlling the output, so I think I'd have to change those to something else.
This is what the circuit looks like now:


The IPA50R180C7 has a threshold voltage that is potentially 4 V. With a 5 V supply for your 555, the FET might only just barely conduct. Even if the threshold were best case, i.e. 3 V, the FET would have serious resistance, and at 180 V at the drain, your FET would get very hot. Increase the supply voltage for your 555 to at least 9 V. 12 V recommended.
Edit: The UF3C120150 you replaced the IPA50R180C7 with in your edit has an even higher range of threshold voltages. 3.5 V to 5.5 V. You must drive the gate with a voltage significantly higher than the threshold voltage to turn the MOSFET fully on.

Hi. The thread is here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/733152/100v-power-supply-from-180v-source/733155?noredirect=1#comment1949911_733155 I also edited this post with more updated information. Thanks

@vol.2 please put that information in your question, so that others do not need to hunt for it.

Okay. Thanks. It seems like I need to figure out how to get the DC offset that was present in the original circuit.  Not sure how to get that correct.

@vol.2 the way to get that correct is to raise the supply voltage for the 555. The output of the 555 will be about 2V less than the supply voltage.
